# onBackPressed event is not working properly in webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am developing an android app using webview. after a button is clicked it navigates to other page. i used javascript function `onClick()` to navigate.when back button is pressed it used to close that application but i want it to navigate to previous page. after using following code it states "unfortunately, myapp stopped working". I tried all possible ways. please help me

```
package com.example.anush.teamcetrankevaluator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView web;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView web=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webview.html");
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // finish the activity
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && web.canGoBack()) {
           web.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Logcat Error :

```
09-10 20:44:52.688  10542-10542/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-10 20:44:52.690  10542-10542/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.anush.teamcetrankevaluator, PID: 10542
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.anush.teamcetrankevaluator.MainActivity.onKeyDown(MainActivity.java:65)
            at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2622)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2714)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2221)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3988)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3950)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3528)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3638)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3536)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3528)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3536)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3528)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3671)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3832)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2210)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1851)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1842)
            at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2187)
            at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
09-10 20:44:54.495  10542-10542/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 10542 SIG: 9
```

Comment: log cat error report

Answer (score 2):

Edit your onBackPressed to look like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // get rid of this --> super.onBackPressed();
    if (web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        // get rid of this --> finish();
    }
}
```

You've also got an error in onCreate:

```
WebView web;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // this line is wrong: WebView web=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    //should be:
    web=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);

    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/webview.html");
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

}
```

This line is the useful part of your logcat error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
```

It means that web was null, but you were trying to do web.canGoBack();

Comment: can you paste the logcat error into your question please?

Answer (score 0):

You create your variable `WebView web` in the main activity and then declare the same variable in the oncreate method. By doing this, you cannot access this initialised variable `web` outside of the scope of the oncreate bundle.

So the variable that you are attempting to access, the class variable `WebView web` that you declared first is not initialised, this is what is causing your app to stop.

So as the other answer Joe says, just

```
web=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

within your oncreate bundle.

This is a link which discusses variable scope in java.
http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

**edit** just saw your logcat:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
>               at com.example.anush.teamcetrankevaluator.MainActivity.onKeyDown(MainActivity.java:65)
>               at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2622)

The null object reference is referring to the uninitialised Webview web, when there is an attempt to access it in your onKeyDown method.

Comment: can you please provide any link on how to use splash in android